# Handle StackOverflowException in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to do something with my application before a StackOverflowException occurs in ASP.NET MVC 4 C#. I'm aware that when a StackOverflowException occurs, the application is killed by the OS (in this case it kills IIS). My question is, is there a way to catch that exception to make a log before it crashes? I tried using HandleProcesCorruptedStateExceptions but it doesn't work. Here's a sample code of what should be achieved.

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
public ActionResult StackOverflow()
{
    try
    {
        Self("test");
        return View();
    }
    catch (System.StackOverflowException ex)
    {
        //log
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        // try to do something to prevent application from crashing
        throw;
    }
}

[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
[SecurityCritical]
private string Self(string value)
{
    try
    {
        return Self(value);
    }
    catch (System.StackOverflowException ex)
    {
        // log
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        // try to do something to prevent application from crashing
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked in the Windows event logs to see if something is logged when the app is killed?

Comment: The nature of a stack overflow precludes anything like this. There's no way to know the exception is going to be raised until the stack overflows and the exception is raised. Until that happens, everything is still copacetic.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, in the Windows event logs it just says that the app has crashed. No information about what crashed it.